# SQL -percent calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, window-functions

Make a report on the sales in 2015 of the products by categories (total value and
quantity sold). Also determine what% of the value of sales
for a given category represent the sales of each of the products in the category.

My query so far:

```
WITH sales AS
            (SELECT t1.category_name
            ,       t2.product_name
            ,      (t3.unit_price*t3.quantity) Total_sales
            ,      EXTRACT (YEAR FROM order_date) Year
            FROM categories t1
                    INNER JOIN
                 products t2 
                    ON t2.category_id=t1.category_id
                    INNER JOIN
                 order_details t3
                    ON t3.product_id=t2.product_id
                    INNER JOIN
                 orders t4
                    ON t4.order_id=t3.order_id
            WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM order_date) = '2015'
            GROUP BY  t1.category_name
            ,         t2.product_name
            ,         (t3.unit_price*t3.quantity)
            ,         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM order_date)
            ORDER BY 1
                    )
SELECT s.category_name
,      s.product_name
,      SUM (Total_sales)
FROM sales s
GROUP BY s.category_name
,        s.product_name
ORDER BY 1
```

How to calculate %? Thank you

Comment: Tables data example, query result example?

Comment: Category Name | Product Name | Sales 2015 ($) | % Sales 2015 (category) | Quantity (units) | - result example

Comment: Categories - t1      Products t2      Order details t3        Orders t4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want window functions - if your database, that you did not specify, supports them:

```
SELECT 
    c.category_name
    p.product_name
    SUM(od.unit_price * od.quantity) as total_sales
    1.0 * SUM(od.unit_price * od.quantity) 
        / SUM(SUM(od.unit_price * od.quantity)) OVER(PARTITION BY c.category_id)
        as category_sales_ratio
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN products t2 p    ON p.category_id = c.ategory_id
INNER JOIN order_details od ON od.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN orders o         ON o.order_id = od.order_id
WHERE o.order_date >= '2015-01-01' AND o.order_date < '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY c.category_id, c.ategory_name, p.product_id, p.product_name
ORDER BY c.category_name, p.product_name
```

The window sum computes the total sales for the whole category, that you can divide the sales of the current product with.

Note that I changed your query in serveral ways:

- *meaningful* table aliases make the query easier to write, read and maintain
- filtering dates without transformation is much more efficient that using date functions
- there is no need for a subquery
- it is always a good idea to put the relevant primary keys in the `GROUP BY` clause (in case two different products or categories have the same name) - on the other hand, you also had additiona uneeded columns in that clause

Comment: My database is called Northwind in Oracle